# How to grep two IP addresses and increase the value of the last number?

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I'm pretty new to Linux and writing scripts etc. I have this task where I need to find an IP-address from a database and then grep a bunch of files with this IP and the next one to see, if they have any presence there. Currently I have to first write:

```
rwhois -Br 0.0.0.0
```

and then

```
grep -wl '0.0.0.0\|0.0.0.1' /path/to/some/files
```

And I have to manually change the last digit from the rwhois and from the grep. 
I got as far as to write a simple function like this

```
function info () {
    rhowis -Br $1
    grep -w '$1\|$1'
}
```

But of course I'd have to somehow increase the value of the latter input by 1. Any good advice? And a small explanation of what you changed is appreciated so I can learn from this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple to just increase the last digit with `awk`:

```
info() {
    local ip="$1"
    local nextip=$(awk -F. '{ print $1 "." $2 "." $3 "." ($4+1) }' <<<"$1")
    rhowis -Br "$ip"
    grep -w "$ip\|$nextip'
}
```

Note that this will not handle wrapping (when the last digit is `255`), but that shouldn't be a problem if you don't need to handle broadcast addresses.

Comment: Thank you a lot! This saves me a bunch of time.

Answer (score 1):

```
ip=$(awk -F\. '{ print $1"."$2"."$3"."($4+1) }' <<< $1)
```

With awk you can set up a variable ip. We set the delimited as "." and then take in the initial IP address then printing out the first,second and third delimited pieces along with the fourth incremented by one.

We would then action:

```
grep -w '$1\|$ip'
```